# Is there a contracted form only for a true condition?

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there a contracted syntax that allows the execution of a certain function only if the left value is true?
Example :

```
ready() ? drawGraph();
```

I do not want this:

```
ready() ? drawGraph() : ELSEFUNCTION;
```

Thanks

Comment: An if statement should work. Otherwise `ELSEFUNCTION` can be a noop.

Comment: It would be of great help to know which programming language we are talking about in order to answer your question.

Comment: @renemadsen It is labeled as a dart question.

Comment: @renemadsen you find in the label..

Comment: Thanks, but I search a contract syntax

Comment: `ready() ? drawGraph() : {};`

Comment: Just use a single `if` statement. Far more clear. The ternary `?` operator is meant for assignments. You could omit the braces if you find that to be too much for some reason.